# TopDesk overview

Tags: java, php, asp.net

I'm creating a overview of TopDesk. I've wanted to ask some of you what the best way would be to get this done.

At the end the application will be set on a big screen so everyone could see how many topdesk calls we have.

I've thought of the following options:

- Web based. (PHP or ASP/.NET)
- Java application

Could someone get me started on this one?

Comment: TopDesk, is that a purely web based application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TOPdesk 4.x is a webapplication, and it already has functionality to create overviews and reports of this type of information. So ideally you could just use the existing functionality and display it on a big screen.

You could als contact TOPdesk themselves for additional information. If what you want cannot be done with the standard features, there is a chance that they (for some things) can also provide bespoke work solutions.

Full disclosure: I worked for TOPdesk a few years ago

If you are talking about TOPdesk 3.x without TOPdesk Application Server (TAS), then things will be a bit harder.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I'll take a closer look at TopDesk and contact them if needed ;)!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could contact our Support department? They can probably answer your question: http://www.topdesk.com/en/support/overview/

@Coulton TOPdesk is available as a web based application as well as a local installation.